# Batch File creation - Change extension, remove line

Tags: batch-file

I have files in directory C:\DIR A\FOLDER A
the files have an extension ABC and are really xml files with an extra line at the top. The extra line reads "ABC0.0.01"

Using a batch file process I want to
1) Copy the files to directory C:\DIR B\FOLDER B
2) Remove the extra text "ABC0.0.01" from the top of the copied files
3) Change the file extension on the copied/edited files from .ABC to .XML

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: I assume that you are under windows, wich type of batch file you would to use, vbs, bat, powershell ?

Comment: Hi - sorry this is not my area of expertise - bat file. Once they are converted to XML proper I can get the data I need.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Have you tried it on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd "C:\DIR A\FOLDER A"
for %%a in (*) do (
  more +1 "%%~a" > "C:\DIR B\FOLDER B\%%~na.xml"
)
```

see `for /?` and `more /?` for details.

Comment: That's brilliant. Don't understand how that removes the ""ABC0.0.01" but it does

Comment: `more +1` does this ("skip 1 line(s)"). Although it doesn't care what is written in that one line.

Comment: `more` converts _tabs_ to _spaces_; this should usually be no problem for XML files though...